# Power BI Loop & Filtering. Complex condition for Row Level Security

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I need help in looping through a set of rows. The number of rows to loop through is dynamic based on the User logging in.

Tables -
Orders table - List of all Orders & each Order has a BillTo, Shipper, Receiver & Fleet Codes
Permissions table (each user has permissions defined based on one or more of the above codes). A user also gets permissions from different groups as shown below -

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29M7u.png)

I can also perform my permissions table in the following way -

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdyG8.png)

(AND condition between the columns & UNION of results of all rows)

A user can have access to one or more of these codes and these codes come from different groups. There is one catch though -
For a given group, the User should have access to Orders which have ALL (not ANY) of the codes matching. If a User has access to 2 BillTo Codes, 2 Shipper & 1 Receiver code from a dataset then my filter condition on OrderLevel would be - WHERE BillTo in (BillToCodes) AND Shipper in (ShipperCodes) AND Receiver in (ReceiverCodes)
We do this on all groups the User has access to & finally do a UNION (NOT INTERSECTION) of the OrderList from each of these groups

A User can have access defined using 1 or n groups. The access can be defined based on any of these codes (A User can have access to only BillTo or only Shipper or only Receiver or a combination of BillTo, Shipper or BillTo, Receiver or Receiver, Shipper codes or all 3)

I’m able to pass the UserId to Power BI & filter the Permissions table based on the User login.
My next steps would be to -
Identify the distinct groups a user has access to
Loop over these groups
For each group, get the Codes (one or more types) the User has access to
Identify Order Nos which have all of these codes matching & store them in a variable
Add Order Nos from all the groups to this variable
Use this variable to filter the OrderLevel table using the OrderNos from the above variable

Let’s say I want to create a 3rd table with the list of OrdeNos the signed in User has access to based on the Permissions of the User as defined in the Permissions table.
SQL statement would be something like this (let's say a user has codes defined based on 3 groups)
Group1 - BillTo Codes, Shipper Codes, Fleet Codes
Group2 - BillTo, Shipper & Receiver Codes
Group3 - Receiver & Fleet Codes

SELECT OrderNo FROM ORDERS WHERE
(BillTo IN (Group1*BillTo codes) AND Shipper IN (Group1*Shipper codes) AND Fleet IN (Group1Fleet codes))   OR
(BillTo IN (Group2BillTo codes) AND Receiver IN (Group2Receiver codes))   OR
(Receiver IN (Group3Receiver codes) AND Fleet IN (Group3Fleet codes))

Can someone please help with the implementation in Power BI?

I already have a simple RLS in place which just filters for the list of codes a user has access to. Now the UserPermissions has an extra attribute called groups. A user can have access defined based on any number of groups. So for each user, I need to iterate over these dynamically.